# Display markdown with css

Tags: html, css, latex, markdown, pandoc

I have 2 file, `style.css` and `index.md`, there is a symbol `\LaTeX` in it, I want to convert the file to `html` first and then convert the `html` file to `pdf`.
After executing command`pandoc --standalone -c style.css -o index.html index.md`, the output file `index.html` lost the `\LaTeX` .
[image]

---

Files included `doc.md`

```
First title
=============
Second title
---
Second title
---
$\LaTeX$

$E=mc^2$
```

---

and `style.css`,which used to control the layout structure of the contents.

```
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

/* Title of the resume */
h1 {
    font-size: 55px;
    color: #757575;
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
h1:hover {
    background-color: #757575;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333;
}

/* Titles of categories */
h2 {
    color: #397249;
}
/* There is a bar just before each category */
h2:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right:1%;
    width: 16%;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #9CB770;
}
h2:hover {
    background-color: #397249;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333;
}

/* Definitions */
dt {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 17%;
    /*font-weight: bold;*/
}
dd {
    margin-left: 17%;
}
p {
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:7px;
}

/* Blockquotes */
blockquote {
    text-align: center
}

/* Links */
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #397249;
}
a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #397249;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333;
}

/* Horizontal separators */
hr {
    color: #A6A6A6;
}
```

My question is how to implement my initial idea in a right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you put between dollars in pandoc markdown is considered math. To render math in HTML [pandoc gives you several options](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#math-rendering-in-html), try e.g.:

```
echo '$\LaTeX$' | pandoc --mathjax -s -o output.html
```

Why? Without `--mathjax` or `--mathml`, (from the [MANUAL](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#math)):

> The default is to render TeX math as far as possible using Unicode characters

But for `\LaTeX`, there is no unicode fallback implemented, thus you get a warning, but the output is still `<span class="math inline">$\LaTeX$</span>`.